# Should we edit posts with foul language?

Tags: discussion, editing, flagging

I came across a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/335078/recommendations-for-good-ftp-server-for-win-2008-x64) today that included some mild profanity. I'm not sure if I've come across swearing in questions before, but this is the first time it has bothered me.

Should we edit posts to remove profanity in order to make them more professional?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, definitely, and as you see, this example has already been dealt with.